# How to calculate the wavelength of the sound in the tube in terms of $L_1$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, frequency, wavelength

> A speaker emitting a sound of frequency 450 Hz is placed above a tube of 54.0 cm high that is filled with water as shown in Figure 1.1. The water is allowed to flow out of the tube slowly. A loud sound is heard when the length
> of air column in the tube is L 1 and again when the length is L 2.

[image]

And what if the third loud sound is heard when the water runs out fully inside the
tube, what is the temperature of the air in the tube?

Comment: find out what standing wave can occur with one open and one closed end to find the wavelength and then by $c=f*\lambda$ the speed of sound.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would tend to avoid using (c) to represent the speed of sound (which is a function of the temperature).

Answer (score 2):

A resonant standing wave in the tube will have a node at the water surface and an anti-node just outside of the open end. The distance, $L_2 – L_1$ = λ/2.